# "ip neigh flush" command removes entries with "extern_learn" and "permanent" set

Tags: linux, ip, iproute2

If arp/neighbor entries are programmed with both "extern_learn" and "permanent", "ip neigh flush" command throws "Invalid argument" error, but the entries are removed. Since they are control plane programmed entries, they should't be removed. Is this a known issue?

For example,

```
ip neigh show|grep 1.2.3.4        
1.2.3.4 dev Vlan100 lladdr 00:00:11:22:33:44 extern_learn  PERMANENT

ip neigh flush 1.2.3.4        
Failed to send flush request: Invalid argument

ip neigh show|grep 1.2.3.4         
====> returns nothing
```

for your info

```
uname -a    
Linux sonic 4.19.0-9-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

The API that `ip` uses is the same API was used to program the entries in the first place, and now they're getting removed the same way that the "control plane" would remove them – for all it knows, they could've been *added* by hand through `ip neigh add` with the same flags.

The optional 'protocol' field should be used to distinguish entries added by the control plane. It is commonly seen in the routing table; e.g. manually added routes default to 'proto boot', BIRD tags its own routes 'proto bird', Quagga/FRR tags its 'proto zebra' – so one can use `ip route flush proto boot` to avoid deleting the automatically configured ones. (Looks like this doesn't quite work properly for neighbour table yet.)